# Zend Studio 9 Debugging - See all of a variables contents

Tags: php, zend-studio

When debugging in Zend Studio 9, if I hover over a variable I can only see a portion of it's content, up to 1024.  I have a var that has a ton of text assigned to it.

How can I view the entire contents of a variable in Zend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in the debugging perspective, you should have a 'Variables' view and 'Parameter Stack' view (usually in the right panel).  It should list all variables in current scope (including globals like the $_POST and $_GET arrays).  In either of these you should be able to see the full values being stored--you can even drill into arrays and objects.

You won't have these in the PHP perspective by default, but you can add them by going Window->Show View->Other and selecting them from the 'debug' folder.

Comment: Hi Ray - I can see my var view on the right as you mentioned, I have outline and a couple of other tabs as well, but when I hover over this particular variable, I can see that it is not showing me the entire content.  One thing, next to the variable in the side panel I see 1024/7432, so it's displaying only the first 1024 chars, I need to see the rest because, as luck would have it, the part I really need to see is closer to the end of the var string.

Comment: @user1176783 when in the variable view, if you select a variable the box below should see the entire variable content.  Are you saying this box is limited to 1024 chars?

Comment: @user1176783  This window box under the variables in the Variable view that shows variable content can be right clicked and you can set the max length of characters to show in the window.  If you set it to '0' it's unlimited and will show 100% of any variable, though I'd cap it at a few 10K's of characters.